# Changing a String Value to Date format in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I am working on a VBA scripting in Excel. The following is the code that i am working on.

```
    Option Explicit

Sub MoveThingsAbout()

Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells.Clear

Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = "JOB"
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1").Value = "STOCKCODE"
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C1").Value = "DATE"
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D1").Value = "QUANTITY TO MAKE"
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E1").Value = "QUANTITY MANUFACTURED"


  Dim row As Integer
  Dim fromdate As String
  Dim stockCode As String
  Dim todate As String
  Dim innerRow As Integer


   fromdate = ""
   todate = ""
   stockCode = ""

   stockCode = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
    fromdate = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2").Value
    todate = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F2").Value


    innerRow = 2
    row = 2
    Do While (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & innerRow).Value <> "")

        innerdate = ""
        innerStockCode = ""

        innerdate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & innerRow).value
        innerStockCode = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & innerRow).Value

         If (stockCode = innerStockCode And (innerdate >= fromdate And innerdate <= todate)) Then

            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & innerRow).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & innerRow).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & innerRow).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U" & innerRow).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("V" & innerRow).Value

         End If

       innerRow = innerRow + 1
       row = row + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

In this Code, i using a condition of comparing the innerdate to fromdate and todate. But the fromdate and todate is user defined. They are in string format. But the innerdate is in a custom format ("dd/mm/yyyy h:mm") as it is retrieved from sql. So i cant change the format of the innerdate. Therefore i have to change the format for fromdate and todate, so that the condition will work properly.

Is it possible to take the string value given by the user for fromdate and todate and change it to the desired format at the VBA level? or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDate function creates a date from any valid **date expression**

From the Excel vba help:

> **date expression**
>
> Any expression that can be interpreted as a date,
>   including date literals, numbers that look like dates, strings that
>   look like dates, and dates returned from functions. A date expression
>   is limited to numbers or strings, in any combination, that can
>   represent a date from January 1, 100 – December 31, 9999.
>
> Dates are stored as part of a real number. Values to the left of the
>   decimal represent the date; values to the right of the decimal
>   represent the time. Negative numbers represent dates prior to December
>   30, 1899.

Comment: thanks for the information. But i am new to VBA. can i know the syntax for using this CDate function. How do i insert it to my code?

Comment: I suggest that you use the vba help system